# Cannot link in Eclipse

Tags: linker, eclipse-cdt

I am using Eclipse to write a C project. I am trying to call functions defined in other files. I use the MinGW C Linker, and I tried to tweak in Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Tool Settings > MinGW C Linker > Libraries.

Before changing anything here, I had the error message:

> undefined reference to `name_of_fct_called'

After adding the libraries names and path in MinGW C Linker > Libraries, I now get:

> Cannot find -lname_of_file

Comment: Please add to your question exactly what you added `in MinGW C Linker > Libraries`.